# How to have a perl variable act as a hash and an object?

Tags: perl

In perl, I'm trying to create a variable `$foo` that I can do both of the following on:

```
$foo->getBirthday();     # (A)
$foo->{'name'};          # (B)
```

How can I do this?

I understand that if I create a perl object then I can have a getBirthday subroutine, but if I do that; how can I use the `->{'name'}` syntax also?  Similarly, if I create a basic perl hash reference, then I can do B, but I don't know how I would accomplish A.

Can someone show me how to create a data structure/object that allows both these syntaxes?

I'm pretty sure this is legal in some fashion since I've seen it in other people's code.  (Unfortunately, its not possible for me to look through their source or run their program)

Comment: My perl is rusty but I'm going to say 'not possible'

Comment: I'm not sure that `perl` follows the `everything is an object` idiom that something like `ruby` does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is legal in some fashion since I've seen it in other people's code. (Unfortunately, its not possible for me to look through their source or run their program)

Comment: This is fine, and if you form your object from a hash reference then it just happens like that. However you are breaking some rules if you access the contents of the hash directly and you should write accessors instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your object is a blessed hash reference, it's *still a hash reference*.  You can (although arguably shouldn't) just access its elements as you normally would a hash:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

package Foo;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $hashref = {
    name => 'bob',
    dob  => '1985-01-01',
  };
  return bless $hashref, $class;
}

sub getBirthday {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->{dob};
}

package main;

my $f = Foo->new;
say $f->getBirthday;
say $f->{name};
```

Comment: Exactly. Although it's a strange object that has constant data items! Much better as `@{$hashref}{qw/ name dob /} = @_` and `my $f = Foo->new('bob', '1985-01-01')`